# Calculate the target point by using initial coordinate, bearing angle and distance

Tags: coordinate-system, c#, visual-studio, wpf

I need to calculate the target coordinate by using the initial coordinate, bearing angle and distance. I came across [this](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) on how to calculate it. Then I construct the code in C#, but it seems I can't get exact location correctly. I use below code this my answer:

```
Target latitude :6.34374176458679
Target longitude : 206.297566445544
```

When I use the application from the website i mention it get this:

```
Destination point:  03° 10′ 28″ N, 103° 08′ 15″ E /Lat:3.174444° Lon:103.150833°
Final bearing:  040° 24′ 37″
```

That are most accurate. Has anybody used this kind of method?

**EDIT:**

```
        //bearing angle 
        double rad = 40.41;
        rad *= Math.PI / 180;

        //angDist = distance/radius
        double angDist = 0.717 / 6371;

        Console.WriteLine("Angular distance:" + angDist);

        double latitude =  3.169416;
        double longitude = 103.146690;

        latitude *= Math.PI / 180;
        longitude *= Math.PI / 180;

        double lat2 = Math.Asin(Math.Sin(latitude)*Math.Cos(angDist)+Math.Cos(latitude)*Math.Sin(angDist)*Math.Cos(rad));

        double forAtana = Math.Sin(rad) * Math.Sin(angDist) * Math.Cos(latitude);
        double forAtanb = Math.Cos(angDist)-Math.Sin(latitude)*Math.Sin(lat2);

        double lon2 = longitude + Math.Atan2(forAtana,forAtanb);


        double finalLat = latitude + lat2;
        double finalLon = longitude + lon2;

        finalLat *=  180 / Math.PI;
        finalLon *=  180 / Math.PI;

        Console.WriteLine("Target latitude :" + finalLat);

        Console.WriteLine("Target longitude : " + finalLon);

        // supposely final answer should be Lat:3.174444° Lon:103.150833° (using the movable-type website)


        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Your code is using 6378137 (ellipsoid semi-major axis), not 6371000 (sphere radius).

Comment: @mkennedy i edit the code using 6371 km (sphere radius) but still i dont get the same value as i the application on [this](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) website.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are adding `lat1` (decimal degrees) + `lat2` (radians).

`lat2` and `lon2` are final latitude and longitude in radians. Just convert them to degrees.

UPDATE: I don't know the language, but must to be something like:

```
double finalLat = lat2 * 180 / Math.PI;  
double finalLon = lon2 * 180 / Math.PI;

Console.WriteLine("Target latitude : " + finalLat); 
Console.WriteLine("Target longitude : " + finalLon);
```

---

(Also, they are using `Radius = 6371 km`.)

Comment: I just correct the comment you give. I use radius 6371 km, but it still not get the exact target coordinate. I get this result Target latitude :6.34374176458679
Target longitude : 206.297566445544.

Comment: I just update my answer to be a bit more explicit.

Comment: i already edit my code, but the final lat/lon value still far from the result i got using the application on [this](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) website.

Comment: Because you are adding them, don't add. `lat2` is the final latitude. `lon2` is the final longitude.

Answer (score 0):

This final code that will get the target point by using initial coordinate, bearing angle to target point and distance. I get this reference from [this](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) website.

```
        double rad = 64.10;
        rad *= Math.PI / 180;

        double angDist = 0.343 / 6371;

        Console.WriteLine("Angular distance:" + angDist);

        double latitude =   3.170620;
        double longitude = 103.151279;

        latitude *= Math.PI / 180;
        longitude *= Math.PI / 180;

        double lat2 = Math.Asin(Math.Sin(latitude)*Math.Cos(angDist)+Math.Cos(latitude)*Math.Sin(angDist)*Math.Cos(rad));

        double forAtana = Math.Sin(rad) * Math.Sin(angDist) * Math.Cos(latitude);
        double forAtanb = Math.Cos(angDist)-Math.Sin(latitude)*Math.Sin(lat2);

        double lon2 = longitude + Math.Atan2(forAtana,forAtanb);


        //double finalLat = latitude + lat2;
        //double finalLon = longitude + lon2;

        lat2 *=  180 / Math.PI;
        lon2 *=  180 / Math.PI;

        Console.WriteLine("Target latitude :" + lat2);

        Console.WriteLine("Target longitude : " + lon2);



        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Please let me know more about rad = 64.10; and angDist = 0.343 . How you got these two points?

Comment: @ManishJain the **rad** value from my code is my location bearing to the target location. Meanwhile the value for **angDist** are from formula angular distance = d/R, **d** is the distance that i specify to the target location and **R** is constant value of Earth radius. You can check [this](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) website , where i get the reference for calculation above. I hope it will help.